# Simple representation for "under the condition that"

Tags: expressions, writing

I'm writing a academic paper, and would like to represent "under the condition that" more simply.

In (very redundant) representation, what I'd like to say is:

> We determined the observation points under the condition that the
>   distances between every two observation points are approximately 500
>   meter.

Is the following representation correct?

> We determined the observations points for the distance of each of them to be approximately 500 meter.

Mmm, I don't feel it sounds correct... Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about using **where**?

> We identified observation points **where** distances between every point are approximately 500 metres.